# Is there any possible way to have another iterator in an iteration loop?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector here, and now I need to use another iterator to peek the vector and see whether the lookahead is a string "assign" or an integer value.

```
bool Val(vector<struct token>token_list){
    vector<struct token>::iterator iter = token_list.begin();
    vector<struct token>::iterator peeker = token_list.begin(); 
    for(iter; iter!=token_list.end(); ++iter){
        if(iter->type == "id"){
            //peeker+=1;
            cout<<peeker->type<<endl;  //check the type: assign / inum      
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems no luck, is there any possible way to have another iterator in a iteration loop? Thanks a lot. ;(

Comment: `peeker++`? (and test against `end ()`).  Or better, perhaps, `vector<struct token>::iterator peeker = std::next (iter)`

Comment: You can create as many iterators as you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an iterator that references the element after a given iterator just create it:

```
for(auto iter = collection.cbegin(), end = collection.cend(); end != iter; ++iter) {
  ...
  auto peeker = iter + 1;
  ...
}
```